# How do I create a MeetupAPI key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, web-scraping, meetup

I am trying to scrape some data in Python ([see tutorial](https://pypi.org/project/meetup-api/)) using the MeetUP API ([see documentation](https://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/)). However I was not able to figure out how I can create an API key to continue my code. Can anyone help me?

I thought the key was the OAuth registration ([see form](https://secure.meetup.com/meetup_api/oauth_consumers/create/)), however I have never worked with OAuth and I do not know how it really works. If OAuth is the key, what are the fields "Application Website" and "Redirect URL" in the form?

Best wishes,